# Include cmake project in Android.mk

Tags: android, cmake, android.mk

Is there a way to include a cmake file? I'm building something for android, and I've found some dependencies I want to use in my project but they have CMakeList.txt files instead of Android.mk.

https://github.com/kubo/funchook

which depends on

https://github.com/capstone-engine/capstone/

So I need to be able to build both of them.

Here is my current folder structure (without the dependencies above:

```
├── build.gradle
├── jni
│   ├── Android.mk
│   ├── Application.mk
│   ├── example.cpp
│   └── libcxx
└── src
    └── main
        └── AndroidManifest.xml
```

Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := example
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := example.cpp
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libcxx
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)

include jni/libcxx/Android.mk
```

Application.mk

```
APP_ABI      := armeabi-v7a arm64-v8a x86 x86_64
APP_CPPFLAGS := -std=c++17 -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden
APP_STL      := none
APP_PLATFORM := android-21
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="native" />
```

Comment: Including a `CMake` based project directly in an `Android.mk` file is not possible, you need to build your `CMake` project separately and then include the prebuilt library. Alternatively, you can consider refactoring your project to use `CMake` instead of `Android.mk`

Comment: @Abdo21 I can't generate the Makefile with cmake and include it in my Android.mk ?